# how to unit test controller which uses this.get('store')

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, mocha.js, sinon

I am unit testing my controller using mocha. My controller looks like:

```
AS.MyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin, {

    name: null,
    description: null,

    init: function () {
        this._super();

        this.get('store').find('something');
    },
    ....
});
```

And my test begins like:

```
describe("MyControllerTest", function () {
    //tried but didn't work
    //delete AS.MyController.init;
    var controller = AS.MyController.create();
    .....
})
```

and the browser always throws error on "this.get('store')" call in init. I am not sure if I need to stub things out or there is a work around for it because my test case doesn't rely on store at all. In either case, I couldn't find much out there and would really appreciate any feedback.

Thanks, Dee

**JSBIN** : http://jsbin.com/aMASeq/3/

**UPDATE :**
There can be many ways to tackle this issue, but what I ended up doing is re-structuring the controller code a bit by putting all the function calls to store into separate actions and then in init I make calls to these action functions using this.send('actioName'). In my unit test, before instantiating the controller, I reopen the controller to modify these action functions(its easier to change action function than to change init function itself, when trying to change init I always got into some js error). Eg:

```
AS.MyController.reopen({actions: {setSomeActionThatUsesStore: function () {
         //do something that doesn't involve using store
        }}});
```

Comment: Why you are calling the store find inside of init?

Comment: I have a select element in handlebar template which is populated by the content returned by that find call. I do not have router for this controller either, because i call it via "render controller" in another template.

Comment: And what is the error throwed?

Comment: I get TypeError: this.get(...) is null, I have added jsfiddle link to my original post too that throws same error.

Answer (score 2):

Controllers get access to the store from the container. You can create a mock container and instantiate the controller with it.

```
var mockContainer = new Ember.Container();
mockContainer.register('store:main', Ember.Object.extend({ 
  find: function() { ... }
});

var controller = App.PostController.create({ container: mockContainer });
```

If you need access to the real `store` then you can just grab the controller from your App's container.

```
var controller = App.__container__.lookup('controller:post');
```

That will instantiate a `PostController` for you that has all of it's dependencies (such as store) wired together.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for the response, I tried :
var mockContainer = new Ember.Container();
    mockContainer.register('store:main', { find: function() {
        console.log("here");
        return null;
    }});
    var controller =  AS.AnalyticsTemplateNewController.create({ container: mockContainer });

but I am still getting "TypeError: this.get(...) is null" error

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your fiddle. 1) You are not creating a store, which you probably should be doing. 2) You are not giving Ember enough time to initialize everything, you just right into testing (see app deferReadiness/setupForTesting. 3) Nitpick, but you are using old versions of ember and data, upgrade to the latest for an improved experience. You might want to read more about setting up your app for testing: http://codingvalue.com/blog/testing-emberjs-guide/

Comment: Hi Ryan thanks for the link, I think it will be a good read. Sorry I just took a working fiddle from the net and modified it to my needs to get some quick feedback - but i'll read through the article and get back to the issue.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions and feel free to share as many fiddles as you need to.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I created a jsbin this time with latest js files in http://jsbin.com/aMASeq/3/. I couldn't find hosted link to expect.js so I just slapped in the whole code in there. I am not sure how to set up the store when I am instantiating controller with create functions. Thanks.

Comment: Oh how I would love to use Qunit, but in my work environment they use mocha and my request to use quint didn't fly well. At the moment I might get by for now by checking ember is in testing mode or not and then skip the store part altogether based on it.