# Routine controller working but failing in test

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm building an Ember app with ember-cli and for some reason a very mundane Controller that works at runtime, fails when being run through tests with the following error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null
```

The controller is nothing more than:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    exerciseTemplates: null,
    setup: function() {
        this.set('exerciseTemplates', this.get('store').find('exercise-template'));
    }.on('init'),

});
```

Any ideas?

---

BTW, here's the stacktrace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null
    at eval [as setup] (trainer/controllers/workouts.js:11:54)
    at sendEvent (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:27786:27)
    at new Class (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:47448:9)
    at Function.Mixin.create.create (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:47903:16)
    at Object.defaultSubject [as subject] (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:200:22)
    at Object.context.(anonymous function) [as subject] (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:217:38)
    at Object.eval (trainer/tests/unit/controllers/workouts-test.js:15:29)
    at Object.wrapper (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:272:31)
    at Object.Test.run (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:1084:18)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:11
```

Comment: duplicate of [how to unit test controller which uses this.get('store')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716232/how-to-unit-test-controller-which-uses-this-getstore)

Comment: The code for the test? It is just the generic test that ember-cli auto generates. I can post this later if you still want to see it.

Comment: Set up a `container` and that should make it work. I'm aware that the question is 1 year old and some things might have changed. If after that you encounter a problem with the new versions, update this question and specify the versions you are using.

Answer (score -1):

The `store` is injected into Controllers as `this.store` - does it work if you change your code to use `this.store` instead of `this.get('store')`?

---

**Update** - trying to provide a more useful answer:

Looking at the on of the [ember-data tests](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/setup-container-test.js) I see there is a `DS._setupContainer` method. From @givanse's comment above I think that adding the following into your test setup might help:

```
var container = new Ember.Container();
DS._setupContainer(container);
```

Comment: Nope. That's what I had to start with. Same result.

Comment: Hi @vitch, just saw your update and tried that as well but doesn't seem to make any difference ... I'm not sure if I fully understand the way in which this code is meant to address the problem. Can you explain?